# jquery how to get the on change event handler function definition

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we know which code is executing on `on change` event  of an element, if I am debugging a jquery code written by someone else and on change event got fired, but i do not know the code that is attached on `on change` event.

For example:

```
$('#someId').on('change', '', function (e) {
    alert("Hello");
});
```

I have already searched for it on internet but did not find anything.

Comment: Have you tried with the developer tools in firefox? See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector/How_to/Examine_event_listeners).

Comment: Chrome devtools also has a list of eventlisteners by (1) event type and (2) element selector. You can find it when inspecting elements in the lower section next to the "styles" tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the event listeners registered on any DOM element. Go to the developer tools of the browser like Google Chrome or Firefox and select the element in the elements tab. Select the event and view all the handlers.
[image: Event listeners on a element in Dev Tools]

Comment: yup found the function that was getting triggered on change of dropdown values